# Create multiple models at once in cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp

What I'm trying to reach is to register a `User` and a `Firm` at once. So I would need to insert into 3 tables: `users`, `firms`, and `firms_users`. CakePHP should do this automatically, because I've set the `$hasAndBelongsToMany` associtation in the models. But during the registration, only the `users` table gets written. Am I missing something?

**registration form**

```
<div class="users form">
<?php echo $this->Form->create('User'); ?>
    <fieldset>
        <legend><?php echo __('Add User'); ?></legend>
        <?php 
        echo $this->Form->input('User.email', array('type' => 'email')); //standard HTML5 email validation
        echo $this->Form->input('User.password');
        echo $this->Form->input('Firm.0.name');
        echo $this->Form->input('Firm.0.zipcode');
    ?>
    </fieldset>
<?php echo $this->Form->end(__('Submit')); ?>
</div>
```

**the relevant part of `User` model**

```
public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
    'Firm' => array(
        'className' => 'Firm',
        'joinTable' => 'firms_users',
        'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
        'associationForeignKey' => 'firm_id',
        'unique' => 'keepExisting',
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => '',
        'limit' => '',
        'offset' => '',
        'finderQuery' => '',
    ),
```

**and the relevant part of `Firm` model**

```
class Firm extends AppModel {

public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array('User'=>array('className'=>'User'));
```

**finally the UsersController / show_reg_form action**

```
public function show_reg_form(){
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            $this->loadModel('Firm');
            $this->User->create();
            $this->Firm->create();
            if ($this->User->saveAll($this->request->data)) {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('The user has been saved'));
                return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'loggedin','loggedin'));
            }
            $this->Session->setFlash(
                __('The user could not be saved. Please, try again.')
            );
        }
}
```

Comment: Do you want save this data in user and firm to, am I right ? it is possible. you can try this
if($this->User->save($this->request->data))
{
   $this->Firm->create();
   $this->Firm->save($this->request->data);
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this code will work

```
public function show_reg_form(){
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            $this->User->create();
            if ($this->User->save($this->request->data)) {
                 $this->Firm->create();
                 if($this->Firm->save($this->request->data))
                 $this->Session->setFlash(__('The user has been saved'));
                 return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'loggedin','loggedin'));
            }
             else{
             $this->Session->setFlash(
                __('The user could not be saved. Please, try again.')
            );
           }
        }
  }
```

Comment: Same problem for three table I have done by this way.I think that will work.

Comment: Since then lots changed, for example now I'm trying to register the Firm first, and only then the user. I've tried the structure you suggested, and now I'm getting an error msg, that `$this->User` (equivalent to `$this->Firm` in your example) is not an object (does not exist).

Comment: Finally, it works with this structure. Thanks for helping. I missed `$this->loadModel('User');` by the way from the action.

Answer (score 1):

It should be

```
echo $this->Form->input('Firm.name');
echo $this->Form->input('Firm.zipcode');
```

Comment: In controller use saveAll metod instead save metod @RápliAndrás

Comment: Could you paste an example, where and how, please?

Answer (score 1):

In order to save with hasAndBelongsToMany association you should have the array like this to save the records

```
Array
(
    [User] => Array
        (
            [field_1] => 1
            [field_2] => 2
            [field_3] => 3
            [field_4] => 4
        )

    [Firm] => Array
        (
            [0] => 5
            [1] => 8
            [2] => 4
        )

)
```

where 5, 8, 4 are the record ids of firm table

I think This is not the case you're looking for, 
I would suggest you to go through the

- `hasMany` association if User has many firms `public $hasMany = array('Firm');`
- `hasOne` association if User has only one firm `public $hasOne = array('Firm');`

so that it will add a Firm when a user is created

Comment: Sorry, my question is wrong, the right one is `firms_users`

Comment: Do you've any records in firms table ?

Comment: I'll try it, but actually Firms can have the same people associated, who are part of other firms, HABTM looks right for this kind of relation

Comment: To work with `HABTM` in your case, first you should have records in your firms table

Comment: That means first adding `Users`, only then adding the `Firm` for it? I've updated the question, so it now shows the action which handles the request.

Answer (score 1):

You can not save data in all three tables using only one saveAll.
First you need to save firm record then assign the new generated firm id as hidden field in $this->data and save user model data with saveAll. Then data will enter in third table named firms_users.
You can check the below link for more information

**http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#saving-related-model-data-habtm**